# How to add a custom uiview to a view controller programmatically SWIFT

Tags: swift, uiview, xib, subview

I am trying to add a custom view programmatically to my view controller. I used this snippet of code with no success of it appearing in front of my main view controller.

```
 var DynamicView = CustomFilter()
    DynamicView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)



    self.view.addSubview(DynamicView)
```

CustomFilter Class:

```
import UIKit
```

class CustomFilter:

```
UIView {
@IBOutlet weak var party: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var outdoors: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var sports: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var diner: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var music: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var gaming: UIButton!
```

}

The custom filter is connected to a xib file.

Xib File:

[image]

Is there a possibility that the custom view maybe out of placed? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: If you want to load a view from a xib... you have to load it from the xib...

Comment: @nhgrif I want to load a xib on top of my view controller. I'm not sure how I can do that. Sorry my question was kind of unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use a view we designed in a xib, we most load from the xib.

```
if 
    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: CustomFilter.self),
    let nib = bundle.loadNibNamed("<#Xib File Name#>", owner: self, options: nil),
    let dynamicView = nib.first as? CustomFilter {

        self.view.addSubview(dynamicView)
}
```

An alternative approach would be to write your `CustomFilter`'s `init` to load the view from the xib itself.

More clearly, the problem you're having is that none of your `CustomFilter`'s initializers are going to care about the xib file you made unless you write them and tell them to care about it.  Your current code is returning a 0x0 view with probably a white or clear background.  If you modified your current code to set the `CustomFilter`'s frame to something other than 0x0 size and set the background color to something like `UIColor.greenColor()`, you'd see it clear as day.

Also, you could use Xcode's visual debugger to find it.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably zero height and zero width, and may be off-screen also.

You need to give it height and width constraints and x and y position constraints.

You should probably also use `CustomFilter(frame: someFrameRect)`, since as I recall initWithFrame is the designated initializer for UIView.

As an aside, variable names should start with a lower-case letter, so `DynamicView` should be `dynamicView`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using the zero-argument initializer.  There's not much point in passing a frame rect when you're going to add autolayout constraints that probably alter the frame anyway...

Comment: I tried your suggestion. The view still doesn't appear. Maybe it is behind my viewcontroller , is that possible?

Comment: @htjohn No.  It's not possible.  A view *controller* is not part of the user interface at all.  It's `view` property is, however you're adding your view as a subview of the view controller's view.  A view can never be behind its parent (or any of its grandparents).